# Retrieve value in XML in vb

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing

I am looking for a more efficient way to retrive the “F” from @agesex in the following XML using VB.

The following is a shortened version of our XML structure:

```
    <GridRow XMLVersion="1.0" ColumnNames="Description|Notes|Detail Question|Detail Question Id">
        <Row>


> ...

        </Row>


> ...

        <Row>
            <NodeLevel>0</NodeLevel>
            <RowData>Cancer|@agesex=F;;|Cancer - Female|2320</RowData>
            <RowStyle>|||</RowStyle>
        </Row>
    </Gridrow>
```

Here is what we have to this point.

```
xmlDoc.LoadXml(topProblemListTemplate.TemplateXml)
            nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/GridRow")

            For Each row As XmlNode In nodeList
                For Each item As XmlNode In row.ChildNodes
                    If item.InnerText.Contains("@agesex") Then
                        Dim index As Integer = item.InnerText.IndexOf("@agesex=") + Len("@agesex=")

                        If index > 0 Then
                            Dim value As String = item.InnerText.Substring(index, 1)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
```

Comment: Are you able to get the <RowData>?

Comment: Yes, We are using a for each loop (item.InnerText.Contains("@agesex") to retrieve the <RowData>.  Please let us know if there is a simple way of doing this using LINQ or XMLDocument.

Comment: Also using indexOf() is not sufficient as the text prior to @agesex could vary.  In this example it is "Cancer" but it could be a different value (ie "Liver Problems").

Answer (score 1):

Using the: [XmlDocument Class (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)

```vb
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim d As New XmlDocument
d.Load("file.xml")
' ... in this specific case (or /GridRow/Row/RowData if you want to be specific)
' ... will select all RowData nodes in the document at least 1 level deep.
Dim _rowNodes As XmlNodeList = d.SelectNodes(".//RowData")
For Each _rowNode As XmlNode in _rowNodes
    If New Regex("@agesex=.", RegexOptions.None).Match(s).ToString.endswith("F") Then
        ' ... doSomething
    End If
Next
' ... example only
Dim _rowNodes As XmlNodeList = d.SelectNodes("//GridRow")
For Each _rowNode As XmlNode in _rowNodes
    ' ... iterating over each GridRow
    For Each _childNode As XmlNode in _rowNode
        ' ... iterating over each Row
        For Each _itemNode As XmlNode in _childNode
            ' ... iterating over Each Item in the Row
            Dim a As String = _itemNode.InnerText.Trim
        Next
        ' ... or can just get the node directly
        Dim b As String = _childNode.SelectSingleNode("RowData").InnerText.Trim
        ' ... to specify properties (assuming fictional gender):
        Dim g As String = "female"
        Dim c As XmlNodeList = _childNode.SelectNodes("RowData[@gender='" & g & "']")
        ' ... also as per the documentation, you can match on the value (the data contained in .InnerText property)
        Dim e As String = "myValue"
        Dim f As XmlNodeList = _childNode.SelectNodes("RowData[.='" & e & "']")
    Next
Next
```

examples: [HOW TO: Use the System.Xml.XmlDocument Class to Run XPath Queries in Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317018/EN-US)

as this document states, the lang/notation used for the queries is: [XPath Examples (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which supports even more selective queries, if you know what data you're looking for.

also, `XML properties` are defined such as:

`<myItem name="myName" gender="female">value</myItem>`

if the gender was a property, it would be much easier, as shown in example above, ie:

`Dim g = "F" : d.SelectNodes(".//RowData[@gender='" & g & "']")`  ;p

Comment: Thank you.  Your example helped us better understand the SelectSingleNoe() properly.

Comment: @MTL323 ok i think that finally does it. pretty much covered it all. if you have any questions, just ask.